# IN clause causing query to run slow

Tags: sql, oracle

For a better performance I am storing variable in Global table and then using it in sub-query but it's the opposite - performance is very slow.If I remove IN clause query performance is faster. Is there any other ways I can use below IN clause differently to optimize performance or any suggestions for better performance. Thanks for any help.

```sql
Insert into GlobalTempTable(
  BranchID; //inserting branchID in gtt, this is not required and can be null
); 

SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderDate, Employee.EmpName
FROM Orders
JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID;
JOIN Employee ON Customers.SalesID = Employee.EmpID;
WHERE Orders.OrDate <= '2020-04-01'
AND (BranchID IS NULL or Employee.BranchID IN (SELECT BranchID FROM GlobalTempTable )); //this IN clause is 
causing query to run slow
```

Comment: Please run an explain plan and post the results.  We know nothing about these tables, #rows, indexes, etc. https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/how-do-i-display-and-read-the-execution-plans-for-a-sql-statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing with `EXISTS`:

```
EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM GlobalTempTable gtt Employee.BranchID = gtt.BranchID )
```

And be sure you have an index on `GlobalTempTable(BranchID)`.

Comment: There is no index in GTT table, it contains only one column. Also I am doing what you sggested but it keep saying missing right paranthesis but all looks good to me. Are we missing Where clause in your suggested subquery

Comment: I think that should be `EXISTS ( SELECT ...`

Comment: @Gordon LInoff thanks for great help, now the performance is fast.